Dax-Count number of categories where the fact value is blank(column from a different table) and replaced on date is blank(column from different table)
Dax measure to Count number of categories where the fact value is blank(column from a different table) and replaced on date is blank(column from different table)
Categories(table 1)
Energy
Emission
Water
Waste
Fact(native units) table 2
100
600
Replaced on (table 3)
2022
2023
2021
Expected output for year 2024 is 1 , water native units is missing and its replaced on date is blank
Blank_category = countrows(filter(summarizecolums(category),isblank(fact) && isblank(replaced on)
But replace on field/column is not being recognized

This is a bit difficult to follow without tables/images. Consider posting some sample data   using this mark down tool to create a table

pls provide some sample data and expected output

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
